# conferences for credit portfolio managers

Tags: risk, portfolio-management, risk-management, credit-risk, soft-question

What are worth conferences for credit portfolio managers?

I appreciate your recommendations!

PS:I am aware that this question is not the typical quant.SE question, BUT I couldn`t find reliable information about this subject.